# Java 17 and Android SDK

Tags: java, android, command, noclassdeffounderror

Hii I want to know if Android sdk is compatible with Java version 17.0.1 ??

Actually I am trying to build an application with command line.... For that I have installed Gradle, java and also installed Android sdk and it's packages like '*command-line tools*' , '*platform tools*' etc...

But when I tried to run sdkmanager it shows this

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
> at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
> at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
> at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
> at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
> at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
> ... 5 more

I have searched the internet and found out that I have to downgrade my java version to 8.... But I don't want to downgrade it..